# sendKeys() in Selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am new to Selenium and I am trying to upload a file using WebDriver. Here I am trying to click browse button using dom element as follows:

```
selenium.type("document.forms['UploadForm'].elements['browsebutton']",file.getAbsolutePath());
```

But since the approach did not work am trying to hit browse button using WebDriver element as below: How can i change my dom element to xpath or css selector as below?

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[type=\"file\"]")).click();
```

I cant write xpath as

```
selenium.click("xpath="//input[@name='uplaod' and @value='browsebutton']");
```

since i have multiple browse buttons with same name and value.. So i need to pick using dom element itself. How do i do it?

Thanks in advance for help.

Dominik i have tried using the below xpath since there is no name attribute:But not working

```
String upload="(//input[@name='bulkUnBlockUploadForm' and @value='requestFile'])[2]";
String button="(//input[@name='bulkUnBlockUploadForm' and @value='process'])[2]";
```

I tried using id as well:Not working

```
   String upload="(//input[@id='content' and @value='requestFile'])[1]";
    String button="(//input[@id='content' and @value='process'])[1]";
```

The issue is in my jsp,i have 2 browse buttons s with same id and same value,but different form.I have 2 submit buttons for each of browse buttons with same id and same value,but different forms.So when am using the above approaches its hitting both the submit buttons

Comment: If you're new to Selenium, take the chance and use **WebDriver**. The Selenium you use now is just an undead!

Comment: You should never us the same `id` for different elements. Make sure the `id` is unique and meaningful, then it's easy to access elements using `driver.findElement(By.id())`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can upload a file, it is work for me.

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
     WebDriver  driver = new FirefoxDriver();
     driver.get("http://www.freepdfconvert.com/");
     driver.findElement(By.id("UploadedFile")).sendKeys("C:\\Users\\Reputa\\Downloads\\HP1.pdf");        
     try {
            Thread.sleep(4000);
        } catch (Exception e) {}
     driver.findElement(By.name("pdfsubmit")).click();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have two buttons with equal attributes, then either rename them to be better accessible (for example by giving them a unique id) or try to change your XPath statement to something like this:

```
String uploadButton1 = "(//input[@name='upload' and @value='browsebutton'])[1]";
String uploadButton2 = "(//input[@name='upload' and @value='browsebutton'])[2]";
driver.findElement(By.xpath(uploadButton1)).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath(uploadButton2)).click();
```

Comment: Dominik as per my test case i wnt to click on 2 browse button.Not on the first matching one

Comment: I have tried but not getting solution.I have edit my question and added tried solutions there.u can refer it

Answer (score 0):

hi when iam beginner i also find a same issue someone told me you cant handle windows controls so use third party application such autoit , iam using autoit.

```
    1. download autoit.
    2. no need of any jars just add Runtime,getruntime().execute('path of exe');in your code
    3.code of file upload is below

Local $hWnd=WinWait("[CLASS:#32770]","",10)
ControlFocus($hWnd,"","Edit1")
Sleep(2000)
ControlSetText($hWnd, "", "Edit1", "path of file to upload")
Sleep(2000)
ControlClick($hWnd, "","Button1");
```

4 run your java application  still if you find query  ask me.